# Is there a sql command I can use to manually start replication?

Tags: sql-server, replication

The title pretty much says it all. I need a command or a script that will manually kick off SQL Server 2012 replication if it is beyond the time it scheduled to start but hasn't yet.

Is there such a thing?

Comment: So when you say "if it is beyond the time it scheduled to start but hasn't yet", does this mean that you have a scheduled job? If so, then you should be able to go into the job and see what the command it is using to start replication.

Answer (score 0):

Sample

-Publisher [ServerName] -PublisherDB [DatabaseName] -Distributor [ServerName] -Publication [PublicationName] -DistributorSecurityMode 1